# 2x2 symetric markov matrix A and Y a vector with entries between 0 and 1, is X a vector with entries between 0 and 1 in AX = Y?

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, symmetric-matrices

I have a matrix
$
   A =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   w & 1-w \\
   1-w & w \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

with $0<w<1/2$

I have $AX = Y$ with $Y = (y_1, y_2)$ with $0\leq y_i \leq 1$

$\rightarrow$ I would like to say something about $X=(x_1, x_2)$, ideally that $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$.

---

Inverting $A$ as $A^{-1} = P^{T}DP = PDP$

with $
   D =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 0 \\
   0 & 2w-1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

and

$
   P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 1 \\
   1 & -1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

gives
$x_1 = \frac{1}{2(2w-1)}(2wy_1 + 2(w-1)y_2)$
and
$x_2 = \frac{1}{2(2w-1)}(2(w-1)y_1 + 2wy_2)$

where, in the case of $x_1$ e.g., $2wy_1$ is always $\geq 0 $ and $2(w-1)y_2$ $\leq 0$.

I am struggling to find whether $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ is always true or not.

Comment: It is not true that $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$. For instance, taking $w = 1/4$ and $y = (1,0)$ leads to $x = (-1/2,3/2)$.

Comment: One thing that you can say is that $X$ lies in the [convex cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) generated by the columns of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I also found couter-exemples but I thought I was wrong as I believed the $0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ held.